# Expand $\ln\left[\frac{(4x^5-x-1)\sqrt{x-7}}{(x^2+1)^3}\right]$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

> Expand this expression to the greatest possible terms with the lowest possible exponents.
>   $\ln\left[\dfrac{(4x^5-x-1)\sqrt{x-7}}{(x^2+1)^3}\right]$

There are two ways at which I approached this problem...
So for the first one, I started out by giving each set of parenthesis their own $\ln$ function:
$\ln(4x^5-x-1)+\ln(\sqrt{x-7})-\ln(x^2+1)^3$

My second approach was to factor out the bottom and then hopefully divide it by the top...
$\ln\left[\dfrac{(4x^5-x-1)\sqrt{x-7}}{x^6+3x^4+3x^2+1}\right]$
And my next plan was to divide $4x^4-x-1$ by $x^6+3x^4+3x^2+1$

Can someone tell me which approach is the correct way, or if they are both wrong. Please **do not** give full answers' only hints.

Comment: You need to check your denominator and what you are doing with that term. As you have written the question you have given it three different values.

Comment: What do you mean? Doesn't $(x^2+1)(x^2+1)(x^2+1)=(x^8-x^2-1)$? OOps, I had a sign mix-up on my paper. Fixing now.

Comment: @AustinBroussard In the first expression you wrote $4x^{\color{red}{5}}$, and in the next big one, $4x^{\color{red}{4}}$.

Comment: Typo... thanks for that

Comment: $(x^2+1)(x^2+1)(x^2+1)=(x^{\color{red}{6}} + 3x^4 + 3x^2 + 1)$

Comment: @Arthur i was thinking of the wrong exponential rule..

Comment: You have also got $x^2+1$ in your first formula, but $x^2-1$ in your first approach

Comment: You might be expected to use $\log r^t = t \log r$

Comment: I'm glad you guys can read, I'm just so tired and I need to sleep after this problem. I can't sleep with an unknown answer!

Comment: I know that, but which approach should I use?

Comment: Which has the lower exponent $x^6$ or $x^2$? There is more problem to know what to do with the square root term, because the question is rather unclearly phrased.

Comment: Well, the square root has the lowest exponent of $\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: How would I write $\ln(4x^5-x-1)$ in $\log r^t=t\log r$ form?

Comment: Are you after an expansion when $x\to+\infty$?

Answer (score 6):

I think what you're expected to do is this. Start with your first approach: $$\log(4x^5-x-1)+\log\sqrt{x-7}-\log\left((x^2+1)^3\right)$$ Now: do you know how to write $\sqrt{x-7}$ in the form $(x-7)^q$ for some cleverly chosen $q$? and do you know how to write $\log a^b$ without any exponents in it? If you can do those two things, you can get the answer that I expect is the intended answer. Note in particular that you can't do anything more with the $\log(4x^5-x-1)$; that already has as many terms with as low exponents as possible.

Comment: +1 for managing to give hints without flatly writing down the answer.

Comment: $\log(4x^5-x-1)+\frac{1}{2}\log(x-7)-3\log(x^2+1)$?

Comment: Yes.${}{}{}{}{}$